# Relationship Between Green's Function and Dirac Delta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dirac-delta, greens-function

In chapter 9 (Green's Functions for Time-Independent Problems) of Haberman's text 'Applied Partial Differential Equations', the author presents the following fundamental result

$$ L[G(x,x_s)] = \delta(x - x_s). \tag{1} $$

So, in words, if the boundary-value problem
\begin{align}
Lu &= f(x)
\\
u(0) = 0 \quad &\mathrm{and} \quad u(L) = 0
\end{align}
admits a solution in terms of a Green's function, the linear differential operator $L$ applied to $G$ yields the Dirac Delta. Now, consider the following specific example -

\begin{align}
 \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} &= f(x)
\\
u(0) = 0 \quad &\mathrm{and} \quad u(L) = 0.
\end{align}

The associated Green's function is then given by

$$ G(x,x_0) = -\frac{2}{L} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ \sin (\,n\pi x/L)\sin(n\pi x_0/L)   }{(n\pi/L)^2}. \tag{2}$$

However, upon applying the differential operator $d^2/dx^2$ to the Green's function, it is easy to see that if $L = 1$ and $x_0 = 1/2$, the resultant will have peaks at regularly spaced values, not just $x_0 = 1/2$. Therefore, strictly speaking,

$$ LG(x,x_0) \neq \delta(x - x_0).$$

Am I missing something?

Comment: In your example, Eq. (1) must hold only in the interval $[0,L]$. The other peaks are located outside that interval.